# How to get product reviews and then click <a> element of product with most reviews (Selenium, Java)

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<section id="135156028" data-scrolled="false" class="AdItem_adOuterHolder__Z29Nf">
     <article class="AdItem_adHolder__GL0yo">
         <a class="Link_link__J4Qd8 Link_inherit___qXEP" target="_self" id="" rel="" role="button" 
                   tabindex="-1" href=".." style="align-items: flex-start;">
             <div class="AdItem_imageHolder__DYGd_" style="max-width: 128px; min-width: 128px; height:                                                              
                         120px;">
                 <img src="...">
             </div>
         </a>
         <div class="AdItem_descriptionHolder__xnkD4">
             <div class="AdItem_adInfoHolder___36KR"></div>
             <div class="AdItem_price__k0rQn">650 din</div>
             <div>
                  <div class="AdItem_viewAndFavorite__pjskf">
                      <div class="AdItem_favoriteHolder__bKBRE">
                          <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" 
                               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="asIcon_greyStroke__NU1Xe  
                               asIcon_svg__Zm34q">
                          </svg>
                          <span class="AdItem_count__iNDqG">**144**</span>
                       </div>
                       <div class="AdItem_favoriteHolder__bKBRE">
                           <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" 
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="asIcon_greyStroke__NU1Xe 
                                asIcon_svg__Zm34q">
                           </svg>
                           <span class="AdItem_count__iNDqG">13</span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="AdItem_postedStatus__C6vfK">...</div>
              </div>
         </div>
      </article>
 </section>
```

This is the code, I deleted some unnecessary thing, but in case I deleted some importat part of the code, link is here: [https://novi.kupujemprodajem.com/mama-i-beba/oprema-za-hranjenje-i-dojenje/grupa/18/2473/1]. I took random product to share code, not the product with most views, but what I want to do is to get views count from here:    "xpath = "//div[@class='AdItem_viewAndFavorite__pjskf']//div[1]"    , to check which product has highest number, and then I want to click on  element of that product. I'm newbie, and I don't know how to connect those, and I didn't find any solutions on the internet.

I tried something like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='AdItem_name__BppRQ']")
    List<WebElement> productsList;
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='AdItem_viewAndFavorite__pjskf']//div[1]")
    List<WebElement> productViewsList;   

public SingleProductPage chooseHighestViewsProduct(){

   String productName;
   String productViews;
   int numberOfViews;
    
   HashMap<Integer,String> mapFinalProducts = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (int i=0;i<productsList.size();i++){
            productName = productsList.get(i).getText();
            productViews = productViewsList.get(i).getText();
            numberOfViews = Integer.parseInt(productViews);
            mapFinalProducts.put(numberOfViews, productName);
        }
   Set<Integer> allKeys = mapFinalProducts.keySet();
   ArrayList<Integer> listOfProductValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(allKeys);
   Collections.sort(listOfProductValues);
   int highestViews = listOfProductValues.get(listOfProductValues.size()-1);
}
```

This way I get the product with most views, but because that span is not clickable, I don't know how to click on its link.

Comment: isn't better if you sort the products by popularity on the website? in this way the first product showed is the one with most views

Comment: i would suggest posting the full HTML because now the description doesn't correspond to the HTML provided. And @soundwave is right, just sort it by the most reviews

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the most views product then find preceding element of `a` tag and then click.

```
productViewsList.get(highestViews).findElement(By.xpath("./preceding::a[1]")).click()
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'findElement' in 'Integer'... Not woring :/

Comment: @StefanItic : Can you try the updated one.